# Firebase Hosting CDN - Sometimes miss already cached images

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cdn

We use the CDN to cache transformed images from a media server, but occasionally while using our website we see a slow downloading images, witch should be already cached. I can see that the image is being served by the media server.

The cache control header is set to: public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000

Any ideas why this is happening?

We are expecting the cached image to stay fresh until we purge the cache or we change the image URL.

Comment: You may be hitting a different caching point of presence, or your asset may be infrequently accessed and drop out of the CDN's cache. No CDN I've used has ever made a promise to *permanently* cache files from the origin or respect super long TTLs; that's why it's called "max age", not "min age".

Comment: You must be very specific. Region, CDN and its configuration, Media type and size, frequency of requests (usage), HTTP request and response including headers. Entries from the CDN logs, etc. The test you are using that shows the CDN has not cached: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging#request_served_from_the_backend. It could be as simple as an overloaded Internet point slowing you down at that instance of time.

Comment: @ceejayoz answers my question, thank you.